# libgdx Music instance obtained from passed reference to object not playing on android but playing on desktop

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx

I am writing an app in Eclipse using LibGdx for a game with two screens. There is also a Question class, which has two instance variables that are Music objects and two that are Strings. The first screen obtains a reference to a Question object and plays the Music instance of the question as well as the Music instance that contains the answer without problems. However, when the second screen is called the reference to this Question object is passed to the second screen but neither of the Music object (obtained from the Question) play any more. I know that the Question is passed on to the second screen because the second screen can access the instance variables of the Question that are Strings but not the Music. 
This problem is only observable when running on Android, when I run the desktop project it all works fine. 
This is the Question class

```
public class QuestionClothsType {
    private int ID;
    private String question;
    private Music questionVoice;
    private String answer;
    private Music answerVoice;
    private String colourAnswer;


public QuestionClothsType(int anID, String aQuestion, Music aVoice, String anAnswer, Music     anAnswerVoice, String aColourAnswer){
        this.ID = anID;
        this.question = aQuestion;
        this.questionVoice = aVoice;
        this.answer = anAnswer;
        this.answerVoice = anAnswerVoice;
        this.colourAnswer = aColourAnswer;
    }

    public int getID(){
        return this.ID;
    }
    public Music getQuestionVoice() {
        return this.questionVoice;
    }
    public String getAnswer(){
        return this.answer;
    }
    public Music getAnswerVoice() {
        return this.answerVoice;
    }
    public String getColourAnswer(){
        return this.colourAnswer;
    }
}
```

This is the relevant part of the second screen:

```
….
Music applause;
Music voiceItem;
Music voiceItem2;
Music voiceItem3;
private QuestionClothsType passedQuestion;
….
public ItemsScreen(Room room, ItemType aType, QuestionClothsType aQuestion){

this.passedQuestion = aQuestion;
voiceItem = passedQuestion.getQuestionVoice();
voiceItem2 = passedQuestion.getQuestionVoice();
voiceItem3 = passedQuestion.getAnswerVoice();
…
private void checkAnswer(int answer2) {
….
if (answerColour.equals(passedQuestion.getColourAnswer())){
        System.out.println("right. the answer was " + passedQuestion.getAnswer());
        applause.play();
        applause.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener(){
        @Override
            public void onCompletion(Music aMusic){
                dispose();
                roomGame.setScreen(new ChestOfDrawersScreen(roomGame));

            }
        }
        );

        }

    else{
        System.out.println("wwrong. the answer was " + passedQuestion.getAnswer());
        mistake.play();
        mistake.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener(){
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(Music aMusic){
                voiceItem2.play();  
            }
        }
        );          
        }

}
….
@Override
public void show() {
    voiceItem.play();
}
```

Neither voiceItem nor voiceItem2 play on Android (both of them are obtained from passedQuestion.getQuestionVoice()) but System.out.println("wwrong. The
 answer was " + passedQuestion.getAnswer()); is printed and it works fine on the desktop.

Thanks for your help.
Carlota

Answer (score 0):

I think you should declare another class for resources. This is happening because android devices are low on resources than desktops so it may not be able to load the required resource in time.
Declare another class with name Resources or whatever you like. and in it do something like this.

```
    public class Resources {
      public static Music myMusic1;
      public static Music myMusic2;
      public static Music myMusic3;

      public Resources() {}

      public static void load() {
         myMusic1 = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("data/mymusic1.mp3"));
         myMusic2 = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("data/mymusic2.mp3"));
         myMusic3 = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("data/mymusic3.wav"));
      }
    }
```

now call this method in your main Game class like this.

```
    public class MyGame extends Game{
      @Override
      public void create() {
         //Here call your method
         Resources.load();
      }

      @Override public void render(int width, int height) {}
    }
```

now go into your custom class where you want to use it.

```
     public class ItemsScreen {
        //----
        private void checkAnswer(int ans) {
            if (ans == 3) {
              //now play music where ever you like in your app. 
              Resources.myMusic1.play();
              Resources.myMusic2.play();
            } else {
              //stop the music from any where in your app.
              Resources.myMusic1.stop();
              Resources.myMusic1.dispose();
              Resources.myMusic3.play();
            }
        }
    }
```

The above example will work on all devices i-e, android, ios, desktop. It's tested. It is a generic example use it anyway you like.